# Using data template and passing a viewmodel from backend

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application. I have separated it into two projects in Visual Studio - a WPF .Net Core project "Frontend" and a .Net Core Console project "Backend".

As the names imply, I am aiming so that one project is concerned only with displaying forms, graphics and everything the user sees, while the other is getting data from the database, performing other business logic and etc.

Currently I have an `ItemsControl` which I want to populate with "Country" objects. I want every item in the items control to display a few values about the country and have a couple buttons tied with data bindings to `RelayCommands` (which is a class which implements `ICommand`).

One way I saw here on StackOverflow was to use a `DataTemplate` for the `ItemsControl` and set it to a `CountryView` (a user control I have created in accordance with the MVVM pattern), like so in a "CountryListView":

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CountrySet}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <views:CountryView/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The problem is that in order to have a collection to bind to, I need to get it from the database. Which is a "Backend" task. However, since the frontend references the backend I can't have the backend populate a set of "CountryViewModel" objects, since that would create a circular dependency. So I improvised and created a "Country" class in the "Backend" project and said task, that gets information from the database, populates a `HashSet` of "Country" objects, which then the front consumes and assigns to the `CountrySet` property of the view model for the "CountryListView".

I have two problems with this approach:

1. The "Country" object can not have `RelayCommand` properties, as that will again be a circular dependency.
2. The "CountryViewModel" is not used at the moment and having a method that just transforms "Country" objects into "CountryViewModel" objects seems like digging myself even deeper into the hole I suppose I am in right now.

The question is **How can I have separate front and back ends and a list of objects on the front end that use a data template which is a custom user control and get populated with data from the back end?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

This question gets asked here all the time, albeit it many different ways. Generally speaking, you are doing the right thing in splitting Country from CountryViewModel. MVVM stands for Model-View-ViewModel...so in your case `Country` is the model, `CountryViewModel` is the view model and `CountryView` is the view. Country belongs in your "backend", the other two belong in your front end.

If you give your `Country` class getters and setters then you can use them in binding, so your view model could be something as simple as this:

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public Country Model {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can just bind your front end directly e.g.:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Name}" />
```

A lot of people seem to assume that they need INPC when actually the don't, but if you do then you can break out individual fields like so:

```
public class CountryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Country Model {get; set;}

    public string Name
    {
        get => this.Model.Name;
        set
        {
            if (value != this.Model.Name)
            {
                this.Model.Name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then there are other options, such as [adding INPC support to your model in a post-processing step](http://www.shenchauhan.com/blog/2018/6/18/fody-inotifypropertychanged-the-easy-way) or using something like [Castle Dynamic Proxy to inject the behaviour at runtime](http://jonas.follesoe.no/oldblog/2009-12-23-automatic-inotifypropertychanged-using-dynamic-proxy/).

So there are numerous options available to you, the best will depend on your personal circumstances.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I tie each "Country" class to each "CountryViewModel" if I am getting all countries' information from the DB and putting them in a set?

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Your database layer should be returning a collection (e.g. a list) of type `Country`. You iterate that list, creating a `CountryViewModel` for each one, and put those in a separate list inside your view model layer that your view layer then binds to.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I thought about that but it seemed too workaround-ish, I thought it would be a code smell.